# Sorting a data range of multiple columns

Tags: excel, sorting, filtering

I'm currently watching about 700 videos about travel with different 80 possible categories throughout.  So my idea is to have the video title in Column A.  Then I have drop down menus that contain the 80 possible categories (Food, Beverage, Desert, Island, etc) in columns B through G.

So for instance

Row 1 - Column A 'Ecuador' - Column B is Food - Column C is Beverage - and Column D is South America

Row 2 - Column A 'France' - Column B is Tourist - Column C is Europe - Column D is Food

Row 3 - Column A 'Egypt' - Column B is Culture - Column C is Africa - Column D is Beverage

And so on for 700 videos.

Now the question is how could I sort or filter the videos by title to find any video that contains 'Food' if Food is found in any column B to G for that row?  I want to make sure the rows stay in tact.

Let me know if my example makes sense or if I need to better illustrate the layout.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you using a programming language? If so, have you tried coding anything for this?

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried any code for this.  What would you suggest?

Comment: I can't say--generally, Stack Overflow is for specific coding questions, so this feels a bit too broad to really offer any advice on, unfortunately. See [ask] and if you can elaborate with something a bit more concrete, that'd be great.

Comment: Yeah it's an excel specific question - is this not the right place to post?

Comment: That helps. Can you post a text excerpt from the sheet? I also recommend tagging the question [excel].

Comment: How can I post a picture?  Sorry for being a noob.  I don't see that as an option anywhere

Comment: It's OK, we're all a noob at something. Generally, [posting images is considered poor practice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) (I'm not sure this applies to excel quite as much though), but maybe a CSV text export with a representative snippet would do the job. I don't actually know anything about excel, so now that it's tagged, hopefully someone will show up and help you out. Best bet is to look at  other excel questions that have upvotes and try to copy their approach. Good luck!

Comment: One possible way you could do this is a helper column that is a concatenation of all the columns you want to filter.  Then use a filter in the helper column with wildcards.  Very easy to implement but not very pretty.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. So without a sample, at least on the expected output, it is very difficult to help you.

Comment: Do not use Excel for this. Use a database.

Comment: any luck on the tries ?

Answer (score 0):

type "search" in H1 cell, then put this formula in H2 :

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND($I$1,B2&" "&C2&" "&D2&" "&E2&" "&F2&" "&G2)>0,1,""),"")
```

and drag downwards.

To use :

1. Type Food in I1
2. Then filter for '1' in column H ("search")

Hope it helps.

note : the space is included to separate the keywords. this search version is case sensitive.

p/s : I'm only covering the " filter the videos by title.." part. Since the criteria for the sort was not defined, I'm not trying it in this solution. ( :

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use COUNTIF:

```
=COUNTIF($B2:$D2,E$1)
```

Much like p.*phidot*'s solution, this would go in an additional column that you would use specifically to filter the spreadsheet. You would type your search term in the header of this column.

You could nest it in an IF function to make it return "Yes" or "No" rather than numbers:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B2:$D2,E$1)>0,"Yes","No")
```